# R: How to update on data table 1 with occurrence of value in table 2

Tags: r

I have two tables:

```
Table 1: 
ID, Name, ...
1, A
2,B

Table 2:
ID, PRODUCT(3 products), COLOR(3 option), number(1)
1, fan, white,1
1, fan, white,1
1, bed, red, 1
2, fan, white,1
```

I want to Add number 9 more column to  table 1. and put count of each combo in the row.

```
 ID, Name, Fan-white, fan-black, fan-blue, bed-white, bed-black, bed-blue, show-white,
 1, A, 2,0....
```

I tried to count and merge each occurrence.  It took a lot of time and code. any Any quick ways?

Comment: add a data set using `dput` and show the desired output; it's not clear what you're asking to do

Comment: I just reformat the question. hope this will explain better.

Comment: still unclear with the data! add rows on next lines!

Comment: Please, [edit] your question and add what you have done so far (your code) and your data (using `dput`).

Answer (score 0):

Here are two different methods to approach this (both involve combining the product and color into a single column).  The first uses `table` which is simpler

```
df1 <- data.frame(id = c(1, 2),
                  name = c("A", "B"))

df2 <- data.frame(id = c(1, 1, 1, 2),
           prod = c("fan", "fan", "bed", "fan"),
           color = c("white", "white", "red", "white"),
           number = 1)

df3 <- data.frame(id = df2$id,
                  prod.color = paste0(df2$prod, "-", df2$color),
                  number = df2$number)

table(df3)

, , number = 1

   prod.color
id  bed-red fan-white
  1       1         2
  2       0         1
```

The second uses two libraries, but might be closer to what you're looking for as `number` can be any value

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

inner_join(df1, df2, by="id") %>%
  mutate(prod.color = paste0(prod, "-", color)) %>%
  select(-one_of(c("prod", "color"))) %>%
  group_by(id, name, prod.color) %>%
  summarise(total = sum(number)) %>%
  spread(prod.color, total, fill = 0)

Source: local data frame [2 x 4]
Groups: id, name [2]

     id   name `bed-red` `fan-white`
* <dbl> <fctr>     <dbl>       <dbl>
1     1      A         1           2
2     2      B         0           1
```

Comment: Thanks for these two solutions! both work perfectly.